# Memory, cache and heap configuration in Neo4j in Windows

Tags: java, configuration, neo4j

I understand that explicit configuration of mapped memory, cache and heap is necessary when running Neo4j with large graphs.

Please provide me with some pointers on how can I change these settings? I realise you need to test with different settings, but what is a good starting point?

Neo4j Community version: 2.2RC01 Java Embedded database

Machine: 8GB RAM

Graph size: 20M nodes(5 properties), 220M edges(2 properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the manual for the config, for RC01 you only have to set the page-cache size, e.g. to 2G

`dbms.pagecache.memory=2g`

You can provide the settings to

`new GraphDatabaseFactory()
      .newGraphDatabaseBuilder(PATH)
      .setConfig(config)
      .newDatabase()`

Heap is configured when you run your java program, via JVM parameters.

Comment: you mean JVM parameters are set via initmemory and maxmemory in neo4j-wrapper.conf file right? also, do you explicitly have to load the properties file as follows? `.loadPropertiesFromFile( pathToConfig + "neo4j.properties" )`

Comment: how do you decide between how much to set for page cache and the heap, out of the available 8GB? Is this mainly testing with different settings?

Comment: if you can afford it align the page-cache with your store sizes, otherwise 4 heap : 2 pagecache (2 for OS)