# Big data import into neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am importing the data around 12 million nodes and 13 million relationships.

First I used the `csv` import with periodic commit 50000 and divided the data into different chunks, but still its taking too much time.

Then I saw the batch insertion method. But for the batch insertion method I have to create new data sets in excel sheet.

Basically I am importing the data from **SqlServer**: first I save the data into csv, then import it into my **neo4j**.

Also, I am using the neo4j community version. I did change the properties for the like all i had found on stackoverflow. But still initially with preiodic commit 50K it goes faster but after 1 million it takes too much time.

Is there anyway to import this data directly from sql in short span of time, as neo4j is famous for its fast working with big data? Any suggestions or help?

Here is the LOAD CSV used (index on numbers(num)) :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50000 load csv with headers from "file:c:/Users/hasham munir/Desktop/Numbers/CRTest2/Numbers.csv" 
AS csvLine fieldterminator ';' 
Merge (Numbers:Number {num: csvLine.Numbers}) return * ; 

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50000 load csv with headers from "file:c:/Users/hasham munir/Desktop/Numbers/CRTest2/Level1.csv" 
AS csvLine fieldterminator ';' 
MERGE (TermNum:Number {num: csvLine.TermNum}) 
MERGE (OrigNum:Number {num: (csvLine.OrigNum)}) 
MERGE (OrigNum)-[r:CALLS ]->(TermNum) return * ;
```

Comment: it would help us if you can share your load csv command and your schema indexes and constraints

Comment: `create index on :Number(num); 

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50000 load csv with headers from "file:c:/Users/ha/Desktop/Numbers/CRTest2/Numbers.csv" AS csvLine fieldterminator ';'

Merge  (Numbers:Number {num: csvLine.Numbers})return * ;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50000 load csv with headers from "file:c:/Users/ha/Desktop/Numbers/CRTest2/Level1.csv" AS csvLine fieldterminator ';'

MERGE  (TermNum:Number {num: csvLine.TermNum})

MERGE (OrigNum:Number {num: (csvLine.OrigNum)})

MERGE (OrigNum)-[r:CALLS ]->(TermNum)

return * ;

`

Comment: please modify your answer with the load csv. can you add also your java heap memory settings and the version of neo4j you are using

Comment: i am using neo4j community version 2.2.0 and java heap memory setting  is -Xmx512m
`create index on :Number(num);` 

`USING PERIODIC COMMIT 50000 load csv with headers from` 

`"file:c:/Users/hasham munir/Desktop/Numbers/CRTest2/Numbers.csv"` 

`AS csvLine fieldterminator ';'`
`Merge  (Numbers:Number {num: csvLine.Numbers})`

Answer (score 3):

How long is it taking?

To give you a reference, my db is about 4m nodes, 650,000 unique relationships, ~10m-15m properties (not as large, but should provide an idea).  It takes me less than 10 minutes to load in the nodes file + set multiple labels, and then load in the relationships file + set the relationships (all via LOAD CSV).  This is also being done on a suped up computer, but if yours is taking hours, I would make some tweaks.

My suggestions are as follows:

- Are you intentionally returning the nodes after the MERGE?  I can't imagine you are doing anything with it, but either way, consider removing the RETURN *.  With RETURN *, you're returning all nodes, relationships, and paths found in the query and that's bound to slow things down. (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-return.html#return-return-all-elements)
- Is the "num" field meant to be unique?  If so, consider adding the following constraints (NOTE: this will also create the index, so no need to create it separately).  I think this might speed up the MERGE (I'm not sure on that), though see next point.

  CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (Numbers:Number) ASSERT Numbers.num IS UNIQUE;
- If the num field is unique AND this is a brand new database (i.e. you're starting from scratch when you run this script), then call CREATE to create the nodes, rather than MERGE (for the creation of the nodes only).
- As was already mentioned by Christophe, you should definitely increase the heap size to around 4g.

Let us know how it goes!

**EDIT 1**
I have not been able to find much relevant information on memory/performance tuning for the Windows version.  What I have found leaves me with a couple of questions, and is potentially outdated.

This is potentially outdated, but provides some background on some of the different settings and the differences between Windows and Linux.
http://blog.bruggen.com/2014/02/some-neo4j-import-tweaks-what-and-where.html

Those differences between Windows & Linux have themselves changed from one version to the next (as demonstrated with the following links)
[Cypher MATCH query speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521401/cypher-match-query-speed?answertab=active#comment47244443_29523946),
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29055966/4471711

Michael's response above seems to indicate that if you're NOT running a java application with Neo4j, you don't need to worry about the heap (-Xmx), however that doesn't seem right in my mind given the other information I saw, but perhaps all of that other info is prior to 2.2.

I have also been through this.
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration.html

So, what I have done is set both heap (-Xmx in the neo4j.vmoptions) and the pagecache to 32g.

Comment: Thanks, Brooks
I am unable to change the java heap i found it in the 
`neo4j-coomunit\bin\neo4j-community.vmoptions` correct me if i am wrong about the location. There is no 'config' file in community. Also, I am using the Merge because the Numbers contains two different type one is incoming and one is outgoing, Sometimes incoming numbers appeared as outgoing number or vice versa in that scenario to avoid the duplication i am using merge. i have tried the create and different constraints on incoming and outgoing nodes. But while using the different constraints i had two nodes for same number.

Comment: I'm assuming from the path you provided, you're using the Windows version?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, is the pagecahe in properties and heap are the same ? because my pagecahe is 10g

Comment: I don't think so, but I'll check when I get into the office and reply back!  Linux and Windows treat the relationship between pagecache and heap differently.  Which OS?

Comment: I edited my answer, but I am not sure if it provides what you need to solve the problem.  How long is the import taking?  And how much ram does your computer have?  Are you doing other memory intensive things while running neo4j?

Comment: my system ram is 8GB. normally when data increased from 1million it takes hours. i was importing the 3million data first 50k in 24 sec. next 50K in 5 min, and then 1 hour.i just change the pagecache to 32g and heap to 4096m.

Comment: after changes i am having this error, 
.
`Starting Neo4j Server failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@14e83f2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.`

Comment: Well first off, pagecache and heap are RAM.  If your system of only has 8GB of ram, you can't allocate 32gb to pagecache and 4gb to heap.  I assume that's the reason for the failure.  I'm also assuming that lack of sufficient ram is the reason for the slow imports and the escalation in time to insert.  Try assigning 5g to pagecache, leave heap commented and see what that does.

Comment: Thanks, brooks i will increase the RAM. I tried not to return the data while creating it. Which worked pretty well but still its slow. I think i need to increase the java heap and for that i need to improve my RAM. I will update you the results after RAM increment.

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify your heap settings to 4096MB.

Also, in the second LOAD CSV, are the numbers used for the two first MERGE already in the database ? If yes use MATCH instead.

I would also commit at a level of 10000.